# Magento: How to create a product during a setup script?

Tags: magento

I am creating a module that needs the presence of one special product.

Did anybody manage to create a new product during a module's setup script?

There are several problems arising, for example `Mage_Core_Model_App::getStore()` is returning the default store as updateMode is set to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work with a data update script (mysql4-data-upgrade-1.0.0-2.0.0.php). In the data `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates()` function the update mode is - in contrast to the normal update scripts - not set to true. The update mode causes problems with creating products.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problem

> Call to a member function getStoreIds() on a non-object in
>   Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php on line ...

by adding the following code at the beginning of my data upgrade script where i create products:

```
Mage::app()->getStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::DISTRO_STORE_ID)->setWebsiteId(1);
```

It is a workaround, but i could not find any other solution.

Comment: are you really using a data update script? Not a normal one?

Comment: Yes, i use a data upgrade script and the problem occurred only during Magento installation, not when running script if Magento is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try the below script for creating a product using SQL setup resource file

// Create Default Products
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$data = array(
 'attribute_set_id'  => $attributeSetId,
 'type_id'      =>  'simple',
 'store_id'   => 0,
 'category_ids' => array($category->getId()),
 'website_ids'  => array(0),
 'sku'    => 'sample-product',
 'name'    => 'Sample Product',
 'description'  => 'Sample Product',
 'short_description' => 'Sample Product',
 'status'   => 1,
 'visibility'  => 4,
 'weight'   => 1,
 'price'    => 100.00,
 'setcustomdefault' => 1,
 'tax_class_id'  => 0,
 'rearimage' => 'rear.png',
 'frontimage' => 'front.png',
 'defaultimage' => 'thumb.jpg',
 'stock_data'  => array('is_in_stock' => 1,'qty' => 20),
 'created_at' =>    strtotime('now')
);
$product->addData($data)
    ->setInitialSetupFlag(true)
    ->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code to create a product programatically:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Varien_Profiler::enable();
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);
Mage::app();

$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();

// Build the product
$product->setSku('some-sku-value-here');
$product->setAttributeSetId('some_int_value_of_some_attribute');
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setName('Some cool product name');
$product->setCategoryIds(array(7)); # some cat id's, my is 7
$product->setWebsiteIDs(array(1)); # Website id, my is 1 (default frontend)
$product->setDescription('Full description here');
$product->setShortDescription('Short description here');
$product->setPrice(39.99); # Set some price   

# Custom created and assigned attributes
$product->setHeight('my_custom_attribute1_val');
$product->setWidth('my_custom_attribute2_val');
$product->setDepth('my_custom_attribute3_val');
$product->setType('my_custom_attribute4_val');

//Default Magento attribute
$product->setWeight(4.0000);

$product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
$product->setStatus(1);
$product->setTaxClassId(0); # My default tax class
$product->setStockData(array(
    'is_in_stock' => 1,
    'qty' => 99999
));

Mage::helper('core')->p($product->getData());
```

After that to save it use $product->save();

Play with this code to get an ideea what it does.

Comment: I used similar code, but it does not work within a setup script!